# Contravariance on constrained generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Referring to this test code compiled for C# in Visual Studio 2010 express

```
public class Test
{
    class Base { }
    class Derived : Base { }

    void Test1(IEnumerable<Derived> derived)
    {
        IEnumerable<Base> b = derived; //This works fine using covariance on IEnumerable
    }

    void Test2<TDerived, TBase>(TDerived derived) where TDerived : TBase
    {
        TBase b = derived; //This works fine because TDerived is constrained to derive from TBase
    }

    void Test3<TDerived, TBase>(IEnumerable<TDerived> derived) where TDerived : TBase
    {
        IEnumerable<TBase> b = derived; //ERROR: paraphrased: Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<TDerived> to IEnumerable<TBase>
    }
}
```

I am attempting to utilize the covariance of IEnumerable to store an enumerable of a generic type parameter within an enumerable of a class that that type parameter is constrained to inherit from. This is exemplified by Test3. Note that Test1 and Test2 (demonstrating covariance on compile time types and assignment of constrained types respectively) both compile fine. It is the combination of the two language features which isn't working for me.

I am able to use `IEnumerable<TBase> b = derived.Cast<TBase>()` and be 100% confident that no cast will fail if my understanding is not flawed so I do have a workaround available. My question is, why does the compiler not allow this? Is this forbidden for some logical reason, an oversight in the compiler, or something else I haven't thought of?

Comment: Jon Skeet already gave the answer. `IEnumerable<out T>` *is* covariant, but covariance only works with reference types in C#. For example if `der` is an `IEnumerable<int>`, then the assignment `IEnumerable<IFormattable> b = der;` won't be allowed. So `Test3<int, IFormattable>(der);` would be a problem, even if an `int` is an `IFormattable`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answer to initial question**

You're currently trying to convert a *single* element of type `TDerived` to a *sequence* of type `Base`. I wouldn't expect your `Cast` call to work either, as `TDerived` doesn't implement `IEnumerable` - I suspect you've actually got that to work in a different situation instead.

I suspect you *actually* meant:

```
void Test3<TDerived>(IEnumerable<TDerived> derived) where TDerived : Base
{
    IEnumerable<Base> b = derived;
}
```

That compiles with no problems.

**Answer to edited question**

Okay, now we've got the *real* problem between two type parameters, the issue is that the compiler doesn't know that they're reference types - which is required for generic variance. You can fix that with a `class` constraint on `TDerived`:

```
void Test3<TDerived, TBase>(IEnumerable<TDerived> derived)
    where TDerived : class, TBase
{
    IEnumerable<TBase> b = derived;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. However I actually made that mistake in trying to boil my problem down to its simplest form. I've revised my question to reflect the more complicated case which is still failing for me. This is the case where the base and derived classes are both generic type parameters.

Comment: @ShaneTapp: This is why it's important to be careful when asking questions, so you don't waste people's time. (Not just me, but everyone else who looked at the question before the edit.) I've edited my answer to reflect the change to the question.